# Logstash shows encountered a retryable error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

My `ELK Version is 7.10.1` and `logstash_csv_report.conf` as follows.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/user/elk/logstash/report.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/home/user/elk/logstash/sincedb.txt"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["start_time", "date", "requester", "full-name", "metric_id", "config", "status"]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     action => "index"
     hosts => "http://elasticsearch:9200"
     index => "build-logs"
    document_id => "%{metric_id}"
  }
stdout {}
```

my csv file size is `599 KB (6,13,652 bytes)` when i tried to insert into elasticsearch, log-stash container shows below error.

```
logstash         |        "message" => "\\xB2\\xD2d\\x83\\xCE\\xFF\\u0003\\u007F6U5O0\\xCB3Y\\xBAS\\xA0\\u0003>\\x80Ӏn\\u000F8$\\xED\\xDAd\\u0014\\xFCLY>\\xCA\\\"`\\u0013,G\\xBE\\xEFs\\u000F\\xBB\\x8B\\u0015\\x81i\\xB6r֘\\x8C\\xC1\\v\\xADH\\x84e\\xAE\\a\\xAEq%\\x99Ѳ\\u001A\\u0002+\\xC0`Y\\u001C\\u001Av\\xA5\\x98\\x99g\\xC3\\xD2lVT\\x83\\xE7WM\\xF9\\x9D\\xF3\\xDBB\\xAB\\xA1\\xBF\\u0005\\xD5\\xFES\\x8C\\xB3\\xFA\\x92\\a\\xD0`v\\xF1\\u0011\\\"\\xFBF\\xEA\\xABGY\\x82o3\\xD8\\a\\xC4G\\xB4\\xBB_\\u0006\\xA2u\\xA9\\xF0\\u0001\\x8Ap\\xB8\\xB9)_y\\x9Fc\\xC9f\\\"\\u0015\\u0018\\x86v\\xDEЙ\\xBAl>\\x94\\u0014\\u0005b|0G\\xA1\\b\\xF0\\xCBX\\xAAM4\\x8E\\u0006*\\x9C\\xDF\\u000F\\xAF\\f\\xB6M\\xBD\\xBEjk\\u001F\\xF0\\v\\xF6\\xF6\\xED\\u001C\\u0013\\u0001\\xC6\\xE8\\x91wS\\r\\u0004e\\x8A|\\x99D\\u0012\\xB4\\xF3z\\xAF\\xA8A\\x8A\\xE6\\xCC",
logstash         |       "@version" => "1",
logstash         |           "host" => "4e6f260d1f67",
logstash         |           "path" => "/home/user/elk/logstash/report.csv",
logstash         |     "@timestamp" => 2021-02-01T13:33:01.163Z
logstash         | }
logstash         | [2021-02-01T13:33:07,940][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][ea93b8cdefefffb2ddfab49df728b916717c4c3a075592951177636abd5be57c] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff  {:code=>400, :url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/_bulk"}
logstash         | [2021-02-01T13:33:15,962][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][ea93b8cdefefffb2ddfab49df728b916717c4c3a075592951177636abd5be57c] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff  {:code=>400, :url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/_bulk"}
```

There is no erorr in Elasticsearch and Kibana side. please provide some pointers to solve this issue.

Comment: Weird that there is no error in the ES server logs, as you're getting an error 400... Can you share the mappings of the `build-log` index?

Comment: Have updated the question with mapping info. here in message section it shows something weird. Actually i have added one column manually in our csv file for eg `status` it has just fail/pass information. if i remove that and run it works normally.

Comment: I don't see the mapping info. What do you get when running `GET build-logs` on your ES cluster?

Comment: It was due to our security tool related. Have worked with them and got resolved. Thanks  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!